# How can we make compass with clickable direction names?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

I want to develop a project based on compass. The compass with all direction name like N (north),  S, E, W, NE, NW, SE, SW.

I also want to perform action on every direction name such that when I click on N, it will show another view controller (xib) with details about North (explanation about north direction).

I have implemented compass as a `UIImageView` with compass image.

I want to make this N as clickable and open another Xib.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add subView with TouchUpEvent or a UIButton to yours kompas view.
Then apply affine rotate to kompas view.

```
...
UIButton * btnN = alloc..initWithType...
btnN.frame = CGRectMake(...)
[btnN addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonNEvent)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[kompasView addSubView:btnN];

kompasView.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(ANGLE, 0, 0, 1);

-(void) buttonNEvent:(UIButton) sender
{
//button N click
}
```